# Placing a div on top of picture under the header

Tags: html, css

I have a website with background image. I also have a header, which fits perfectly on top of the page. What I would like to do now is I would like to add two `<div>`'s under header that sit on top of the image, but it seems impossible. I tried all possible ways of positioning, displays. Also padding for the `<div>`'s doesn't work as well- it pushes the background image down. jsfiddle here:  jsfiddle.net/XqHAj

Here's the html code:

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">    


    <header id="header">
        <h1>Portfolio</h1>
           <div id="menu">
             <ul class="nav">
                <a href="#" id="pull">&#x2630;</a>
                <li><a href="index.php?site=home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?site=about">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?site=works">Works</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?site=contact">Contact</a></li>
             </ul>
           </div>
    </header>

        <div class="container"> 

            <div class="left-container-box">
                Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet porchetta shoulder chuck t-bone kevin rump pork chop landjaeger bresaola shank. Tail ribeye corned beef meatball capicola ham hock, beef ribs tongue jerky swine tri-tip pork chop spare ribs bresaola porchetta. Salami ham ham hock fatback venison, bresaola pork belly pastrami tongue. Jowl pork loin corned beef, spare ribs meatball filet mignon drumstick beef ribs shankle landjaeger pastrami t-bone bresaola. Hamburger ball tip frankfurter pastrami leberkas andouille pork loin pig shoulder. Tail tenderloin t-bone kevin swine tri-tip strip steak boudin bacon pastrami. Frankfurter bacon ribeye, biltong salami pancetta tenderloin.
            </div>

            <div class="right-container-box">

            <div>

        </div>

<div id="wallpaper"><img src="pictures/wallpaper.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt="wallpaper">

</div>

</body>
```

Here's the css code:

```
html
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
body
{   
    font-family: "Sanchez-Regular";
    color:#BBBBBB;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#wallpaper
{
    position:relative;
}

#header{
    width:100%;
    height:6em;
    background-color:#100f0f;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #333232;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #333232;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #333232;
}

/*NAVIGATION BAR STYLING*/
li{
    display:inline;
    padding:3.2em;
    font-size:120%;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.nav{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    list-style-type:none;
}

#menu a{

    list-style-type:none;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#BBBBBB;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}

#menu a:hover{
    color:#807a7a;
}

#pull{
    display:none;
}
#menu{

    margin:auto;  
}
/*NAVIGATION BAR STYLING ENDS*/

/*BODY STYLING*/

.container{

}

.left-container-box{

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you make a fiddle( http://jsfiddle.net ) and post it?

Comment: *"a footer, which fits perfectly on top of the page"*? Some illustrative example(s) of what you want would help.

Comment: @Qtax I was confused by that at first but I think they mean "top" as in "in-front"

Comment: Sure, there you go! :)    http://jsfiddle.net/XqHAj/

Comment: @user2983295 now tell what result or change you are looking for in your fiddle

Comment: I would like to have two vertical divs below the footer that sit on top of the image.

Answer (score 0):

first set the background-image "pictures/wallpaper.jpg in wallpaper div
remove image tag from it

put two div in wallpaper div

Comment: why would that be a good idea? I would like the background image to fit all resolutions.

Comment: then give body background image

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you set a negative `z-index` and `position:absolute` on the div you want "behind" the footer

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vAM95/)

```
.image {
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    z-index:-999;
    bottom:0px;    
}
```

Comment: what z-index wiil do?

Comment: @ChiragSutariya z-index affects the layers so you can sit elements in-front or behind each other

Comment: okay so now I can see the text in front of the background, but how can I move it under the footer?

Comment: @user2983295 when you say "under" do you mean "lower on the screen" or  "underneath" like a lower layer?

Comment: underneath like lower layer I guess?

Comment: If you want the text to go behind the footer, add `z-index:-9999;` and `position:absolute;` to the div with your text

Comment: @Adsy no not behind the footer- lower on the screen in that case. so tired today. sorry :(

Comment: Then just put the code for the div with the text underneath the footer code and set `position:relative;` to the "text div"

Comment: @Adsy hey, I set the z index for the image -999 and now I can see the text on top of the header (yes I was talking about header all the time FOR CRYING OUT LOUD).. As well as the position relative to the text divs. The text code is positioned below the header code, but it still doesn't go lower on the screen.. Any advice?